# What is Conexant D400 External USB 56K Modem .Do I need it to create dial up connection in ubuntu14.04

Tags: networking, modem

I want to know what is Conexant D400 External USB 56K Modem and why it is "external usb"

Comment: If you want to create a dial up connection over your telephone line, you need a modem designed for that interface.  The modem is a device that converts your data to a form that can be sent/received over a telephone connection.  If your computer didn't come with one, you can add one.  Connecting a modem to a USB port is a convenient way to do it.  The specific modem model in your question is just one of myriad models available for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old type of modems kept for legacy support. It's practically no longer used. It allows to make a dial-up connection with a speed of no more than 56Kbps which means 7KB/s. It's also used as a fax interface for the computer which means you may plug in the phone cable and send/receive fax documents.

why it is "external usb"?
Well, some devices have "PCI" parent address which means like if that device is connected to the PCI slot. The same way, some device have "USB" parent address which means like if they have a USB plug connected to a USB port BUT internally.

Comment: THAnks, sorry could not upvote it low reps!!

Comment: Not eager for your upvote sir!

Answer (score 0):

Its a legacy modem - in Win10 its recognised a USB-Com-Port i.e. Com3. If you like to send a fax you use the windows-fax-printer. It tells you there should be a modem for sending the fax, you tell him it is on Com3 and the modem-type is a legacy 56k Faxmodem. Connected to the telephone-line it will send your fax without any problems.